# Attempted to access distanza(2); index out of bounds because numel(distanza)=1 matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I'm working on a project in matlab and I'm having problems on this part of my code.

In the final for loop I can not create an array where to store all the values ​​of 'distanza'..... as output the program overwrites the last value found, or it says that the array has only one value.
I need these values ​​and then make the media.

```
  C(f2)= numel (featPairs);
  C1(f1)= numel (featPairs);

 [bestval,bestidx] = max (C);
 [bestval1,bestidx1] = max (C1);

 a = importdata('coordData.mat'); 

    x = interp1( a(:,1), a(:,2),  1:frames2);
    y = interp1( a(:,1), a(:,3),  1:frames2);

 b = importdata('coordData2.mat'); 

    x1 = interp1( b(:,1), b(:,2),  1:frames1);
    y1 = interp1( b(:,1), b(:,3),  1:frames1);

distanza=[];
dist= [];

if max(C)==bestval

disp ([x(bestidx),y(bestidx)]);
disp ([x1(bestidx1),y1(bestidx1) ]);

for i=1:10 

distanza  = sqrt ((x(bestidx)-x1(bestidx1))^2 + (y(bestidx)-y1(bestidx1))^2);
dist = [dist; distanza(i)];

end

 save ('distance_sample.mat','dist');
 disp (['la distanza tra le due posizioni è: ', num2str(distanza)]);
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: In the `sqrt` line you are computing `distanza` as a single number. In the next line you try to access `distanza(i)`, which gives an error for `i` greater than 1. Maybe just change that second line to `dist = [dist; distanza];`

Comment: I had already tried it but as result it gives me an array with the last value written 10 times! I can not understand what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk trough the code:

```
      C(f2)= numel (featPairs);
      C1(f1)= numel (featPairs);
```

Assuming that `featPairs` exists and `C` and `C1` don't, you just create a vector of zeros that will have overwiritten the same (positive) value in two different positions `f1` and `f2`.

```
     [bestval,bestidx] = max (C);
     [bestval1,bestidx1] = max (C1);
```

This will put in `bestidx` the value of `f1` (i.e. the position of the positive element `f1`) and in `bestidx1` the value of `f2`

```
     a = importdata('coordData.mat'); 

        x = interp1( a(:,1), a(:,2),  1:frames2);
        y = interp1( a(:,1), a(:,3),  1:frames2);

     b = importdata('coordData2.mat'); 

        x1 = interp1( b(:,1), b(:,2),  1:frames1);
        y1 = interp1( b(:,1), b(:,3),  1:frames1);
```

Okay, you load and slice and process some data.

```
    distanza=[];
    dist= [];
```

You create/cleanup `distanza` and `dist` as empty matrices.

```
    if max(C)==bestval
```

This will always be true; please look on how you defined `bestval`. Better to remove it, it serves no purpose.

```
    disp ([x(bestidx),y(bestidx)]);
    disp ([x1(bestidx1),y1(bestidx1) ]);
```

Okay, some more displaying.

```
    for i=1:10
```

For each i from 1 to 10 ...

```
    distanza  = sqrt ((x(bestidx)-x1(bestidx1))^2 + (y(bestidx)-y1(bestidx1))^2);
```

... Rewrite `distanza` as a scalar (euclidean distance). I stress here, **scalar** as in 1x1 matrix. Now, because the right-hand-side does not depend on `i`, it will calculate the same value over and over again, and i stress here **same value**.

```
    dist = [dist; distanza(i)];
```

...append to the right of `dist` the `i`-th element of the scalar `distanza`. Now, when `i` is 1 this is okay, but for the rest of the values you'll get out of bounds (error).

```
    end
```

... end of for loop.

```
     save ('distance_sample.mat','dist');
     disp (['la distanza tra le due posizioni è: ', num2str(distanza)]);
```

Some more saving and displaying.

In my opinion, you should clarify first to yourself what you want to compute, because the code seems a bit disorganized. Now, tried [rubberducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging); it works for me. Hopefully it will work for you too. :-)